# Payara5 + RestEasy 6.0.1 uses Yasson

Tags: java, jackson, resteasy, jackson2, yasson

When we upgraded RestEasy to 6.0.1 on Payara 5, we noticed that Payara now uses Yasson to serialize and deserialize objects, resulting in all @JsonIgnore, @JsonProperty to be ignored. We have added the jersey.config.jsonFeature context-param as specified in the docs:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.jsonFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>JacksonFeature</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Falling back to RestEasy to 3, 4 or 5, Payara 5 again starts using Jackson and all @Json annotations are honored again.

How does RestEasy decide the provider (Yasson vs Jackson) and how can one force Jackson in RestEasy 6.0.1 on Payara?

Comment: Are you using RESTEasy or Jersey? I believe Payara uses Jersey and the property you are setting is for Jersey not RESTEasy.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I am trying to use Rest Easy, which seems to work on Payara prior to RestEasy 6

Comment: I don't know much about Payara, but the only differences in RESTEasy 5.x and 6.x is the Jakarta namespace change. It should behave the same. That said you could try the `resteasy.preferJacksonOverJsonB` context parameter.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a couple of days investigating this, the solution was to:

1. Add jersey-media-json-jackson dependency to the POM:

> ```
>   <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
>       <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
>       <version>2.26</version>
>   </dependency>
> ```

2. Register org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature.class in your Application class like so:

   ```
   @ApplicationPath("services")
    public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature.class);
        // add the rest of your classes here
        return classes;
    }   
    }
   ```